# VMware Fusion 11 - CEIP/telemetry

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I want to try VMware Fusion 11.

One thing that bothers me and prevents from installing it on my Mac
is their Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP) (and other forms of telemetry that might be there).

I reviewed VMware documentation and searched the web and I *believe* that CEIP can be fully disabled,
but I cannot find any reliable information on whether Fusion sends back any other telemetry data.

Their docs suggest that it might be the case, but then it can be just some obsolete information,
from pre-CEIP era.

My question is:

Can VMWare Fusion's CEIP/telemetry be fully disabled,
resulting in no data "leaks", neither from the `.app` nor from kernel extensions (`.kext`-s)?

Comment: Are you in the EU? If so, just ask them... they actually ***have*** to tell you what information may be transmitted & what they may do with it, how long they would keep it, whether any of it would be personally identifiable, etc, etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's something I didn't think about, thanks! I'll share what their reply is. Still, I would appreciate if someone experienced with Fusion shared their real-world experience.